# How to subset values from a list that are similar to values from a second list?

Tags: r, list, subset

List A contains values

```
c("Data 2018.xlsx","Data 2014.xlsx","Regular","Data 2019.xlsx","Data 2020.xlsx")
```

List B contains values

```
c("2022","2021","2020","2019","2018")
```

Is there a way to pull `c("Data 2018.xlsx","Data 2019.xlsx","Data 2020.xlsx")` from List A since "2018","2019" and "2020" were in list B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may expand `b` by adding "Data" and ".xlsx" and find the common intersection with `a`.

```
a <- c("Data 2018.xlsx","Data 2014.xlsx","Regular",
       "Data 2019.xlsx","Data 2020.xlsx")
b <- c("2022","2021","2020","2019","2018")

intersect(sprintf('Data %s.xlsx', b), a)
#[1] "Data 2020.xlsx" "Data 2019.xlsx" "Data 2018.xlsx"
```

---

Another option extracting the numeric value from `a`

```
a[sub('Data (\\d+)\\.xlsx', '\\1', a) %in% b]
```

Or the same using `stringr::str_extract`

```
a[stringr::str_extract(a, "\\d+") %in% b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```r
a[grepl(paste(b, collapse = "|"), a)]
#> [1] "Data 2018.xlsx" "Data 2019.xlsx" "Data 2020.xlsx"
```